# Is there a way to uncheck other items in a pivot table except a specific one?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am new to VBA and I am having some trouble with some code on how to uncheck or deselect all items in a pivot table except a specific one.

I am creating a button to automatically filter data that will only reveal data in January ("20190131") or in February ("20190228") and so on etc.

I still dont have data for October ("20191031"), November and December, which causes error "Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem" because there is still no existing data of those dates. I just want an item to be checked and the rest to be unchecked.

I tried manually setting the visibility of Pivot Items to false and it is taking a long time for excel to uncheck them and I do not want my items to be static. And also if data still is not existing for example the data I am using is only from January 2019 to September 2019.

```
   Sub Procdate_January()

  Procdate_January Macro
  ' Macro for changing the PROCDATE of Pivot Tables in Worksheet 
  "Worksheet1" to "20190131".

Sheets("Worksheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PROCDATE"). _

    CurrentPage = "(All)"

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PROCDATE")
    .PivotItems("20190131").Visible = True

    .PivotItems("20190228").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20190331").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20190430").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20190531").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20190630").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20190731").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20190831").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20190930").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20191031").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20191130").Visible = False

    .PivotItems("20191231").Visible = False

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("XDPI_PROCDATE"). _
    CurrentPage = "(All)"
    End With
End Sub
```

I expect that the output will be the only visible filter in the pivot table will be "20190131". But it gets an error that the other 20190930, 20191031, 20191130, 20191231 cannot be found.

Comment: you can try to put `On Error Resume Next` before the `With ActiveSheet.Piv` statement and put `On Error Goto 0` after the all of your `.Visible` statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one item to select then **DO NOT** set each item one by one or even in a loop. Simply clear the filters and set the value to the relevant value.

See this

**Manual Way**

[image]

**Via VBA Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PivName As String
    Dim PivField As String
    Dim PivValue As String

    '~~> Change as applicable
    Set ws = Sheet1

    PivName = "PivotTable1"
    PivField = "Year"    '~~> PROCDATE in your case?
    PivValue = 2019      '~~> 20190131 in your case?

    With ws.PivotTables(PivName).PivotFields(PivField)
        .ClearAllFilters
        .PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=PivValue
    End With
End Sub
```

> Is there anyway I can put the "PROCDATE" in the "Filter" section in the PivotTable instead of "Rows"?

When you record a macro. You will get something like this

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Year").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Year").CurrentPage = "2014"
```

So simply change the above code to

```
With ws.PivotTables(PivName).PivotFields(PivField)
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = PivValue
End With
```

Comment: I tried the code you've showed me sir and changed the variables but it causes a run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error and highlights this line:

.PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=PivValue , when I tried other options before like looping from other related problems like mine but I also get an error like this.

Comment: **[1.]** What exact code did you try? **[2.]** which excel version are you using? Try `.Add` instead of `.Add2`

Comment: 1. Option Explicit

Sub january()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PivName As String
    Dim PivField As String
    Dim PivValue As String
    
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    PivName = "PivotTable1"
    PivField = "PROCDATE"
    PivValue = 20190131
    
    With ws.PivotTables(PivName).PivotFields(PivField)
    .ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=PivValue
    
    End With
End Sub

2. I am using 2013 version of Excel and I tried .Add instead of .Add2 still the same error.

Comment: Ok record a macro like I showed in the manual way and see what do you get?

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PROCDATE").PivotFilters. _
        Add2 Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:="20190131"
End Sub

This is the code when I view the code of the recorded macro sir.

Comment: Ohhh I saw whats causing the problem, the code you gave me works perfectly fine. Whats wrong is where I put the "PROCDATE" in the PivotTable, I put it in the "Filters" section, I tried putting it in the "Rows" and it works. Is there anyway I can put the "PROCDATE" in the "Filter" section in the PivotTable instead of "Rows"?

Comment: Updated the post. You may have to refresh it to see it

Comment: Been doing this for 2 weeks and I finally got it. Thank you so much for your help.