# Method 'visible' of object 'PivotItem' failed

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

So I have searched around and still none of the solutions work...

I have the following code where if I click the options food from the slicer, it will auto-filter data and only show for >6, and >8 columns.

```
Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
  If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_TABLE_StackChart").SlicerItems("food").Selected = True Then
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Foods_StackChart").PivotFields("FOODS")
      .PivotItems(">0").Visible = False
      .PivotItems(">2").Visible = False
      .PivotItems(">4").Visible = False
      .PivotItems(">6").Visible = True
      .PivotItems(">8").Visible = True
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

I don't know what's wrong, I get this error: Method 'visible' of object 'PivotItem' failed

I generated this code through record macro and just added the If statement and Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate.

It works if I run the one that the record-macro generated but I want it to run automatically when I click the slicer item, it runs but errors out at pivotItems(">0").Visible for some reason even though just running it works...

Comment: What happens when you do it in reverse? I mean start from `">8"` and then go towards `">0"`

Comment: that was auto-generated from record-macro, but let me check in reverse

Comment: still same issue

Comment: See if [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57815285/is-there-a-way-to-uncheck-other-items-in-a-pivot-table-except-a-specific-one) helps?

Comment: didn't :(, there's so many questions related to this yet no viable solution